# Dynamic ThenInclude in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a some includes in my code that I can add them to the query using this code:

```
queryable = IncludeExpressions.Aggregate(queryable, (current, includeExpression) => current.Include(includeExpression)
```

Is there any way to add `.ThenInclude` dynamically? I mean each `.Include()` expression has a list of "then include" clauses that should be applied to it. How can I do that?

I have tried to define an object that key is list of key value. Key is `.Include()` expression and the value is the list of `.ThenInclude()` expressions, however I couldn't make it work.

I tried this code:

```
var queryable = query.Include(includeExpression);
        
var thenIncludes = specification.ThenIncludeExpressions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item1 == includeExpression);

if (thenIncludes is not null)
{
    queryable = thenIncludes.Item2.Aggregate(queryable, (current, thenIncludeExpression) => current.ThenInclude(thenIncludeExpression));
}
```

But it errors because queryable is `IIncludableQueryable<out TEntity, out TProperty>` and for using `ThenInclude` it should cover this method `ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>`

Comment: Add more details, how `ThenIncludeExpressions` looks like and how do you specify such includes.